# Set up Python on Windows to not type "python" in cmd

Tags: python, windows, path, cmd

How do I have to configure so that I don't have to type `python script.py` but simply `script.py` in CMD on Windows?

I added my python directory to %PATH% that contains python.exe but still scripts are not run correctly.

I tried it with django-admin.py Running `django-admin.py startproject mysite` gives me 
`Type 'django-admin.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.` Using python in front of it processes the command correctly.

What's the problem here?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235834/how-to-make-python-scripts-executable-on-windows-7-after-installing-python-3-1-2

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
C:\> assoc .py=Python
C:\> ftype Python="C:\python27\python.exe %1 %*"
```

Or whatever the relevant path is - you can also set command line args using ftype.

---

In order to make a command recognized without having to give the suffix (`.py`), similar to how it works for `.exe` files, add `.py` to the semi-colon separated list of the (global) `PATHEXT` variable.

**ETA 2017-07-27**

Seems like this is still getting eyeballs, wanted to elevate a useful comment for Win10 users (from @shadowrunner):

*For me to get it work under Win10 the actual command was (note the placement of the quotes):*

```
C:\> ftype Python="c:\Anaconda2\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

**ETA 2019-02-01**

Talk about evergreen!

First of all, if you're newly installing Python, I highly recommend reviewing the answer by @NunoAndré .

Secondly, to clarify something from a recent comment, please note: you must do both parts (`assoc` and `ftype`), or use a pre-existing association label in the `ftype` command.

By default, at least for Python 3.7 under Windows 8.1, the association for `.py` is `Python.File`, so performing the `ftype` command I wrote above will not work correctly unless the association is first changed. Or you can just use `ftype` and give the default association instead. Up to you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I never knew about `assoc` or `ftype` before today.

Comment: I set that in CMD with administrative rights but still I cannot execute `django-admin.py --version` without python as a prefix. Without the prefix I get shown the help command is if I had run `django-admin.py -h`.

Comment: Neither did I. :) But I needed one more upvote for comment privs, so to the Windows docs I went.

Comment: @orschiro - sorry, I think my last edit shows the right one. Need to at %0 (replaced by file) and %* (replaced by args).

Comment: That was it! Thanks. I discovered the same just here: http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable

Comment: For me to get it work under Win10 the actual command was (note the placement of the quotes):
```C:\> ftype Python="c:\Anaconda2\python.exe" "%1" %*```

Comment: 1) I can execute directly a .py file from the cmd line (w/o the explicit use of python.exe), even if .py is not among the associations. (I don't know how this is done.) The only problem is that I cannot use arguments! 2) The solution given above -- which I tried -- didn't change anything.  3) What do you mean by "you can also set command line args using ftype"? How? Example? (I really wonder, since arguments are dynamic, whereas 'ftype' is a static thing.

Comment: @Apostolos - Still on Win8.1 here, so don't know if there's anything different happening on Win10. I've also since migrated to Py3. The new Windows installers actually handle a lot common cases, so you may want to try re-installing and paying attention to custom options/settings there? What I meant by setting command line options with ftype, is you can put anything you want in that string. So, you can add switches (-i, etc) and other parameters to pass by default.

Comment: I still need an example about arguments. E.g. if a PY file requests a filename to be passed as an argument, how are you going to form `ftype Python="c:\Anaconda2\python.exe" "%1" %*`  so that one can run `PYfile.py filename` from MSDOS prompt?  In my Windows 7 and with Python 2.7, 'filename' is just ignored. See what I mean?

Comment: I tried to do this, but no luck.Despite what the manual says, mine didn't do this on Win 10.  Maybe something else screwed it up - I had PyCharm for a while, which "grabbed" the association, but even uninstalling it and reinstalling Python didn't fix this issue. After running the commands above `ftype Python` returns `python="C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" "%1" %* ` but it doesn't work anyway.  No error message, just nothing happens when I run `foo.py`.  Running `python foo.py` works fine.

Comment: @jgalak - sorry to hear! I still do not have Windows 10, but, is it possible that .py is not associated to Python? A default install of Python appears to create the association of .py=Python.File (view this via `assoc .py` from CMD). So you would need to change the association or set the Ftype Python.File = instead of Python = .

Comment: @selllikesybok - `assoc .py` returns `.py=Python`.  `ftype Python` returns `Python=C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" "%1" %*`. Still doesn't work though.

Comment: Aha!  I ran the utility suggested by @Nuno André below.  That didn't fix it, but it seems to have reset the association, so the next time I tried to run a `.py` file, I got the Windows screen asking what program to open the file with.  I was able to then set it to the python executable, and it's working now.  Weird...

Answer (score 6):

From Python 3.3 a [launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) is included: `py` (and `pyw` for GUI or non-UI applications)

> which aids in locating and executing of different Python versions. It allows scripts (or the command-line) to indicate a preference for a specific Python version, and will locate and execute that version.
>
> Unlike the PATH variable, the launcher will correctly select the most appropriate version of Python. It will prefer per-user installations over system-wide ones, and orders by language version rather than using the most recently installed version.

Python installer links Python's file extensions to `open` verb by default, so you can run a python file simply by typing its name (and args if needed).

- `py`: `.py`, `.pyc` and `.pyo` ([byte-compiled](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html?highlight=pyc#distutils.util.byte_compile)), and `.pyz` ([zip-compressed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html)).
- `pyw`: `.pyw` and `.pyzw` (zip-compressed).

Caveat: [be aware of the differences between python.exe and pythonw.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe/30313091#30313091)

---

Among other advantages, Windows launcher reads 'nix shebangs, so you can specify Python version or `python.exe`'s [command line arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html)

You can check this running this script (supposing py3 as default):

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7 -i
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

- `myscript.py`: runs with `py`, launches `python2.7` and enters in interactive mode after finished (`-i`, great option for testing and debugging).
- `myscript.py -3`: runs with `py`, launches `python3` and keeps interactive mode.
- `python myscript.py`: runs with default python runtime, no interactive mode.

---

You can change this default association with `ftype`, but I would strongly recommend:

- Nirsoft's [File Types Manager](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) utility.
- Taking a look at msdn docs about file extensions and associations: [Implementing a Custom File Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521657(v=vs.85).aspx).

You can easily associate other verbs (like `edit`, `test`, `debug`...) to these files.

---

In addition, you can omit Python's extensions to run a file in a terminal by adding them to `PATHEXT` environment variable ordered by preference. (You must re-open the terminal for the change to take effect).

`setx PATHEXT %PATHEXT%;.PYC;.PYZ;.PY`

Comment: I have a problem on Windows 10 where running myscript.py in a terminal causes VS Code to open!.
How do I reset this?

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same issue...
I could fix it by re-associating *.py files with the python launcher.

1. Right click on a *.py file and open its properties.
2. Click on the Change button of the "Opens with..." section
3. Select More apps -> Look for another app on this PC.
4. Then browse to your windows folder (by default: "C:\Windows")
5. Select "py.exe"

Comment: This approach has additional advantages compared to the accepted answer: It will take the shebang line of the Python scripts into account and therefore select the correct Python interpreter in case you have e.g. virtual environments in use.

Answer (score 1):

i did a try with :

```
C:\> assoc .py=Python
C:\> ftype Python="C:\tools\python\python.exe %1 %*"
```

It didnt work for me. so i did a ftype search :

```
ftype | find "Python"
Python="c:\tools\python\python.exe" %1 %*
Python.ArchiveFile="C:\Windows\py.exe" "%L" %*
Python.NoConArchiveFile="C:\Windows\pyw.exe" "%L" %*
```

Solved my problem with a slightly other ftype command :

```
ftype Python="c:\tools\python\python.exe" "%L" %*
```