# Avoid Typing "python" Before Django Commands in VS Code

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I am setting up a new Windows 10 computer and somehow on my old Windows 10 computer I was able to configure VS Code so that I do not have to type "python" before Django commands in the VS Code command prompt. For example, I can type "manage.py runserver" instead of "python manage.py runserver". Frustratingly, I can't figure out how to replicate this on my new machine. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set up Python on Windows to not type "python" in cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472843/set-up-python-on-windows-to-not-type-python-in-cmd)

Comment: How about `./manage.py runserver`

Comment: Thanks for the link, Iain! Still having issues after adding and removing python, changing env variables, and setting associations. Here is the error when I try to run "manage.py runserver" without "python" in front, in my pipenv...............ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?