# How can I convert my python script to a package that is callable from the commandline?

Tags: python, module

I'd like to convert my python script to a module that can be called from the commandline. Kind of like pytest or something. 
For instance, my script is named `egscript.py`. I have to run the script like this, `>python3 egscript.py [commandline args]`

What I want instead is to be able to do it like this,
`>egscript [commandline args]`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11473042/13676202), you can use:

```
C:\> assoc .py=Python
C:\> ftype Python="C:\python27\python.exe %1 %*"
```

I suggest you to see the link I put before. If you want to run it as a package like `pip install egscript` and then use `egscript`, you have to create a package to upload it into the Python Package Index(PyPy). To make that posible, follow the steps in these links: [Build Your First pip Package](https://dzone.com/articles/executable-package-pip-install), [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

Comment: I want to do something similar to [this](https://pypi.org/project/pystress/). So that I can distribute it to other systems as well.

Comment: Okay, you mean, run the file, only by his name, without .py, yeah?

Comment: As an application like in the link. So I can also pass the commandline arguments and others can install it via pip

Comment: Oh, okay. You have to create a proyect with your script and then publish it if you want. You have to follow the steps of this [link](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

Comment: You can see this [link1](https://dzone.com/articles/executable-package-pip-install) too. I find it very helpful.

Comment: Glad it helps you, I just added the links to my answer. I'll appreciate your upvote. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could set an alias in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file

```
alias egscript="python3 /path/to/egscript.py"
```

Or you could turn it into an executive using something like [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org), and then you can run the script like `./egscript`