# How to set which python version is used when running python script in Windows without typing python command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have 2 Python versions installed on my PC: 3.7 and 2.7
Only python 3.7 path defined in Windows `PATH` variable.
When I run a script from command line using `python` command:

```
python my_script.py
```

It works. BUT, when I run this script without typing `python` command, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\.......my_script.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

I installed `tkinter` only for python 3, so I assume it tried to run `my_script.py` using python 2

How can I define in Windows to run python scripts using version 3 instead of 2 without typing command `python`?
(adding any sort of `#!...python3` in the beginning of the script did not helped)

Thank you for your help

Comment: you should try [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472843/set-up-python-on-windows-to-not-type-python-in-cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472843/set-up-python-on-windows-to-not-type-python-in-cmd) and specify the path of your 3.7 python virsion

Comment: @seif, thank you this solved my issue