# Run Python script in a machine in which Python is not installed

Tags: python-3.x, executable

I need to run a Python script in another machine that does not support python. I mean something like Visual Basic, you can run the "**Executable**" even though VB is not installed in your machine.

I read something about **web service** but I'm not sure if you can use it with **windows**.

**Is it doable?**

Comment: what is your os?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run python program without 'python' in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828739/run-python-program-without-python-in-windows)

Comment: @wishmaster os: windows10

Comment: is it possible to install py2exe with anaconda for python 3.7?

Comment: yes; https://anaconda.org/kieranharding/py2exe

Comment: it doesn' not support python3.7