# How place python app in startup?

Tags: python, winreg

I want place my python app in startup the windows.

how i write code in python for this work?

this app after complete with using py2exe convert to exe file.

thanks.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/63326/enable-exe-to-run-at-startup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make python scripts executable on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235834/how-to-make-python-scripts-executable-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

If you've created an exe file of your Python program, you will need to add a  shortcut to that file inside of your system startup.

How you do this will depend on which version of Windows you're using.

This YouTube video will show you how to do it for Windows 10.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htkkZGik-Lk

Answer (score 0):

You can place it in

```
C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

You don't have to convert it to exe, just put there .py file