# Installing a package - not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have installed a package called munch on Windows 8.1 from https://github.com/ccampbell/html-muncher

However I am not able to execute a command. When I say on the command line

```
munch --help
```

I get an error that says `munch` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I double checked and saw that `C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Scripts` is added to `PATH`.

How do I troubleshoot?

Comment: Try `python -m munch --help`

Comment: After downloading the repository from github, did you move to that directory and run `python setup.py install`? I installed using the setup script on Ubuntu and I can run `munch --help` with no problems.

Comment: You probably need to say `munch.py --help`. if you want to execute a `.py` file without adding the `.py` extension, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4235923/712526

Comment: Yes I did the same. I ran python setup.py install and it displayed a series of messages, one amongst which said "Installing munch script to C:\Python27\Scripts.

Comment: using munch.py --help is not helping either.

Comment: Does calling it with the full path work?

Comment: Full path? You mean C:\Python27\Scripts\munch --help?