# How do I randomly pick an icon for a pen drive?

Tags: autorun

I've seen a tutorial online that explained how to change the icon of a pen drive once inserted using an `autorun.inf` file and a `.ico` file, and it worked perfectly, but I wanted to know if there's a way to choose a random file from a list of `.ico` files inside the pen drive.

Here's the code I'm using for the normal icon

```
[Autorun]
Icon=IconName.ico
Label=PENDRIVE
```

If this can't be directly done using the `autorun.inf` file, please let me know an alternative method, even if it requires other files (such as `.vbs` files)

Here's the website I used just in case

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-custom-icon-removable-drive-windows-10

Comment: One way to do it would be to use the [open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144200(v=vs.85).aspx#open) command to run a shell script which chooses a random icon, and copies it to a specific file name (such as `random.ico`) each time.

Comment: Then, you could leave the `Icon` command set to `random.ico` permanently. That should change the icon each time you insert; it might not take effect the first time, but it should take effect each time thereafter.

Comment: Ok so I'm very noobie to the Autorun feature. Do I have to create a new file to do the random choosing, or will the "open" command itself do it for me?

Comment: As shown in the `open` link I provided above, open takes the filename of an executable to run. That executable can be written in the programming language of your choice, with the caveat that the language must installed and set up properly in the registry to be automatically recognized for files of a given type.

Comment: This works for batch files already, which is why I suggested it. It might even work for VBScript (which I see you use), and it can be set up for Python.

Comment: For example, you should be able to call python scripts with `open` after completing [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11473042/712526) (which the Python installer [*probably* did for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4235923/712526)).