# Can't run executable file on another computer

Tags: python-2.7, executable

For some reason I can't run an executable file on another computer. I have tried everything, I put all the missing DLL's in the folder, I have put all the music files in the folder. It works perfectly on my computer but I just can't seem to find a way to get it to work on someone elses.

Comment: what kind of computer are you using VS the new computer? could it be a user permission issue `chmod +X`??

Comment: I am using a windows computer and so is the other computer.  And what exactly does chmod+x mean

Comment: `chmod` is a command that allows you to alter file level permissions in unix. the `+x` makes the file executable.

Answer (score 0):

the answer from [How to make python scripts executable on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235834/how-to-make-python-scripts-executable-on-windows)

> This sums it up better than I can say it:
>
> http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html
>
> More specifically, check out the 2nd section titled "How do I make Python scripts executable?"
>
> On Windows, the standard Python installer already associates the .py extension with a file type (Python.File) and gives that file type an open command that runs the interpreter (D:\Program Files\Python\python.exe "%1" %*). This is enough to make scripts executable from the command prompt as foo.py. If you’d rather be able to execute the script by simple typing foo with no extension you need to add .py to the PATHEXT environment variable.