# How to run a python program from powershell based on python hashbang?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, powershell, shebang

I have several python3 scripts using the *hashbang* for identifying it as a Python3 script. The scripts can *not* be identified as python based on the file extension, as they don't have any (just like in any other *nix system).

I've already looked at related issues, but they don't address this particular need, and seem to rely upon the `*.py` extension, for recognition.

- [Set up Python on Windows to not type "python" in cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472843/set-up-python-on-windows-to-not-type-python-in-cmd)
- [How to make python scripts executable on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235834/how-to-make-python-scripts-executable-on-windows)

So my script is named: **`myscript`**, and the first line of the file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
...
```

**How can I make Windows *powershell* recognize this and run it with the python interpreter located in `C:\Python3.7`?**

---

**UPDATE-1**

To clarify, I want to run it from *powershell* CLI and not by clicking on it.
In addition, I just discovered (to my horror) that when you use `pip install` with a native Windows Python3, the first line *hashbang* is autotragically replaced with:

**`#!c:\python37\python.exe`**

Ouch!

---

**UPDATE-2**

Thanks to @eryksun's comments, I managed to get a PowerShell script to do some basic checking for me. However, it will need to be fixed to support more than Python.

**`test4script.ps1`**:

```bsh
Param([parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="Need a valid filename")] $fileName)
$firstLine = Get-Content -Path $fileName -TotalCount 1
$SHEBANG="^#!"
$shes=@("python3","python2","python","bash","sh","perl","pwsh")

If ($firstLine -match $SHEBANG) {
    Write-Host "DEBUG: checking for common shebangs" -ForegroundColor Green
    foreach ($i in $shes) {
        If ($firstLine -match $i) {
            Write-Host "DEBUG: found shebang for: $i" -ForegroundColor Green
            C:\python37\python.exe $fileName
            break
        }
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "File is not a known script. No shebang fund in file!" -ForegroundColor Red
    return
}
Write-Host "DEBUG: Done" -ForegroundColor Green
```

The result is:

```sh
$ Get-Content -Path nonscript -TotalCount 3
#This aint right
echo "hello"

$ Get-Content -Path pip-describe -TotalCount 3
#!c:\python37\python.exe
# pip-describe - Show full text package description from PyPI
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

$ .\test4script.ps1 nonscript
File is not a known script. No shebang fund in file!

$ .\test4script.ps1 pip-describe
DEBUG: checking for common shebangs
DEBUG: found shebang for: python3

 Usage:  pip-describe <package-name>

 This will return the full-text package description (usually the README)
 as found on PyPI, for any given <package-name>.
 ...
```

Now we should be able to associate this script with **`.`**, using **CMD.exe** with:

```
cmd /c assoc .=unknown
cmd /c "ftype unknown=""C:\mybin\test4script.ps1"" %1"
```

But it would have been nicer to do this independently with PowerShell and not having to hop through CMD.

Comment: What have you tried so far? My thought is you'd write a script that introspects each file, looks for that hashbang, then runs the file in Python if it matches. Is there any part of that that seems impossible?

Comment: Not much, as I have no good idea of where to start. I'm able to do the opposite by running powershell scripts (using the **pwsh** hasbang) in Bash, but not this. What would be the correct way to check this in powershell? The tricky hack would be to have your pwsh interpreter to understand when you type: `./myscript`, and run it.

Comment: Oh, if that's your intention then that's good info to have in your post - I didn't realize you just wanted to be able to run `./myscript` and have it work.

Comment: Perhaps one could leverage the windows build of [file](https://superuser.com/a/1379687/116221)?

Comment: `#!c:\python37\python.exe` is a valid shebang for the py.exe launcher, which by default the installer associates with .py files. The launcher will execute any fully-qualified path, and it also supports virtual shebangs such as `#!/usr/bin/python3` and `#!python3`. You could write a program that implements an association for the "." file extension (i.e. filenames with no extension). If it's a Python shebang, run it via py.exe. Getting CMD to run a file without an extension requires adding "." to the `PATHEXT` environment variable. PowerShell is probably the same.

Comment: @eryksun Very good info there! I had no idea about those additional shebangs. I was surprised that *installed* files are actually modified in this way. Changing the association of **`.`** sound promising. So you're suggesting to make PS script that checks the shebang and have the dot (`.`) associated with it?

Comment: The "." file association would be to a ProgId that defines an "open" template command line, which runs an executable or script that handles a subset of shebangs (maybe extendable with a plugin architecture). If it starts a process to run the file, it has to wait on the child process and proxy the exit status.

Comment: If you're only concerned with Python scripts, you could associate "." with the `Python.File` ProgId. However, the py.exe launcher will execute any file with the default Python version if there's no recognizable shebang with a virtual or fully-qualified executable path. You probably don't want double-clicking on a "README" file to run `"path/to/python.exe" "path/to/README"`. We need a shebang handler that's more generic than py.exe.

Comment: I think my update will put us one step closer to a more generic shebang handler. Much needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) provides great pointers in comments on the question, and your edits based on them show the way toward installing **a generic, machine-wide shebang-line-aware launcher for extension-less scripts made executable by adding `.` to `$env:PATHEXT`**.

Things to note about this approach:

- **PowerShell currently (as of PowerShell Core 6.2.0) invariably executes extension-less files in a *new* console window**, which makes this configuration useless *in PowerShell* - it does work as expected from `cmd.exe`, though.

  - PowerShell's behavior should be considered a **bug** and was reported in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9430).
- **The mechanism presents a potential security risk**, because any plain-text file without an extension that has a shebang line effectively becomes executable, potentially bypassing security features that focus on files that have extensions known to be executable.
- Implementing a file-type definition's default operation via a [PowerShell] script invariably requires creating a *child process* with the script file's interpreter, which in the case at hand means invoking `powershell.exe` with its `-File` parameter. **`powershell.exe`'s startup performance cost is nontrivial, which delays execution**.
- **If you *do* want to implement this generic mechanism after all, see the 
  `Install-ShebangSupport.ps1` script at the bottom.**

---

Given the above, here's a ***more lightweight, Python-specific approach* based on automatically creating *individual `*.ps1` wrapper scripts* for extension-less shebang-line Python scripts**:

This takes advantage of the fact that PowerShell allows execution of its own `*.ps1` script files by filename only.

**Limitations**:

- You need to run the wrapper-script-generation script (printed below) at least once, and every time you add new extension-less Python scripts.
- Conceivably, a file-system watcher could be used to trigger the generation script, but setting that up is a nontrivial effort.

On the plus side, the wrapper scripts execute more quickly than a generic file-type-based solution, because no extra PowerShell instance (child process) is involved.

Run the following script from the directory in which the extension-less Python scripts are located<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Where-Object Extension -eq ''  | % { 
  if ((Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.fullname -First 1) -match '^#!.*\bpython') {
    @'
py.exe ($PSCommandPath -replace '\.ps1$') $Args; exit $LASTEXITCODE
'@ > ($_.FullName + '.ps1')
  }
}
```

For every extension-less Python script `somescript`, a companion `somescript.ps1` file is created that passes `somescript` to the Python launcher `py.exe`, along with any command-line arguments; `exit $LASTEXTICODE` ensures that `py.exe`'s exit code is passed through.
As eryksun notes, `py.exe` should be capable of interpreting the shebang line to invoke the appropriate Python executable.

If you don't want to clutter your system with wrapper *files*, **auto-generate *functions* as an alternative**, but note that you'll have to load them into every session to be available, typically via your `$PROFILE` file:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Where-Object Extension -eq ''  | % { 
  if ((Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName -First 1) -match '^#!.*\bpython') {
    Invoke-Expression @"
    Function global:$($_.Name) {
      py.exe "$($_.FullName)" `$Args
    }
"@
  }
}
```

**Note**:

- This will make the current directory's extension-less Python scripts available *as if they were located in a directory listed in `$env:PATH`* - whether or not the current directory is listed there.
- Each target Python script is hard-coded into a function of the same name and will *invariably* target that script.

  - By contrast, the `*.ps1` wrapper script-file approach permits targeted invocation in a given directory, with something like `.\foo`.
- This particular use of `Invoke-Expression` is safe - to define the functions based on expandable strings - but [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

---

#### Script `Install-ShebangSupport.ps1` for installing generic support for direct execution of extension-less shebang-line-based scripts on Windows:

- The script supports installation at the *current-user* level (by default or with `-Scope CurrentUser`) or at the *all-users* level (with `-Scope AllUsers`, requires running as admin).
- Assuming presence in the current dir, run `Get-Help .\Install-ShebangSupport` for basic help.
  Invoking the script without arguments prints a confirmation prompt with details about the required modifications to the system; <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> can be used to abort without installation; passing `-Force` performs installation without prompting for confirmation.
- To uninstall later, pass `-Uninstall`; note that you must match the (implied) `-Scope` value used during installation.

<sup>**Implementation note**: Defining the no-extension file type via the `cmd.exe`-internal commands `assoc` and `ftype` invariably takes effect for *all users*, because the definitions are stored in the registry in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`; also, the invocation therefore invariably requires elevation (administrative privileges).

However, it *is* possible to create *user-level* definitions by direct manipulation of the registry, which is what this script uses, also for the machine-level definitions.</sup>

<sup>Note: Syntax highlighting is broken in the code below, but it does work.</sup>

```bsh
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Support for direct execution of extension-less script files with shebang lines
on Windows.

.DESCRIPTION
For details, invoke this script without arguments: the confirmation prompt
will show the required modifications to your system. Submit "N" to opt out
of the installation.

Note that extension-less files that do not have a shebang line will open in 
the default text editor.

.PARAMETER Scope
Whether to install support for the current user only (the default) or
for all users (requires invocation as admin).

.PARAMETER Uninstall
Uninstalls previously installed support.
Note that the (implied) -Scope value must match the one that was used during
installation.

.PARAMETER Force
Bypasses the confirmation prompt that is shown by default.

.EXAMPLE
Install-ShebangSupport

Installation for the current user that requires answering a confirmation prompt.

.EXAMPLE
Install-ShebangSupport -Scope AllUsers -Force

Installation for all users without confirmation prompt. Requires invocation
as admin.

.EXAMPLE
Install-ShebangSupport -Uninstall

Uninstallation for the current user with confirmation prompt.
#>

[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]
param(
  [ValidateSet('CurrentUser', 'AllUsers')]
  [string] $Scope = 'CurrentUser'
  ,
  [switch] $Force
  ,
  [switch] $Uninstall
)

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; Set-StrictMode -Version 1
if ($env:OS -ne 'Windows_NT') { Throw ("This script can only run on Windows.")}

# ---------------------- BEGIN: Internal helper functions

# === INSTALL
function install {

  Write-Verbose ('Installing shebang-script support for {0}:' -f ('the current user', 'ALL users')[$forAllUsers])

  # NOTE:
  #  * assoc and ftype only ever operate on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes, not HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes - both on reading and writing.
  #  * *HKEY_CURRENT_USER*-level definitions DO work, but *neither assoc nor ftype report them or can update them*.
  # Therefore, we perform direct registry manipulation below.

  Write-Verbose 'Creating file type for extension-less file names via the registry...'

  # Map the "extension-less extension", "." to the name of the new file type to be created below.
  # Caveat: Sadly, New-Item -Force blindly recreates the registry key if it already exists, discarding
  #         all existing content in the process.
  $key = New-Item -Force -Path $regkeyExtensionToFileType
  $null = New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $key.PSPath  -Name '(default)' -Value $fileTypeName

  # Define the new file type:
  $key = New-Item -Force -Path "$regkeyFileType\Shell\Open\Command"
  $null = New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $key.PSPath  -Name '(default)' -Value ('powershell.exe -noprofile -file "{0}" "%1" %*' -f $helperScriptFullName)

  # Get the current $env:PATHEXT definition from the registry.
  $currPathExt = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATHEXT', ('User', 'Machine')[$forAllUsers])
  if (-not $forAllUsers -and -not $currPathExt) {
    Write-Verbose "Creating a static user-level copy of the machine-level PATHEXT environment variable..."
    $currPathExt = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATHEXT', 'Machine')
  }

  # Add "." as an executable extension to $env:PATHEXT so as to support
  # direct execution of extension-less files.
  if ($currPathExt -split ';' -notcontains '.') {
    Write-Verbose "Appending '.' to PATHEXT..."
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATHEXT', $currPathExt + ';.', ('User', 'Machine')[$forAllUsers])
    # Also define it for the running session
    $env:PATHEXT += ';.'
  } else {
    Write-Verbose "'.' is already contained in PATHEXT."
  }

  # The following here-string is the source code for the
  # $helperScriptFullName script to create.
  # To debug and/or modify it:
  #   * Edit and/or debug $helperScriptFullName
  #   * After applying fixes / enhancements, replace the here-string
  #     below with the updated source code.
  @'
  # When invoked by direct execution of a script file via the file-type definition, the arguments are:
  #  * The full path of the script file being invoked.
  #  * Arguments passed to the script file on invocation, if any.
  #    CAVEAT: PowerShell's own parsing of command-line arguments into $args
  #            breaks unquoted tokens such as >> -true:blue << and >> -true.blue << into *2* arguments
  #            ('-true:', 'blue' and '-true', '.blue', respectively).
  #            The only way to avoid that is to pass the argument *quoted*: '-true:blue' and '-true.blue'
  #            See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6360

  # Parse the arguments into the script
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $LiteralPath,
    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)] [array] $passThruArgs
   )

  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; Set-StrictMode -Version 1

  # Note: When invoked via the file-type definition, $LiteralPath is guaranteed to be a full path.
  # To also support interactive use of this script (for debugging), we resolve the script 
  # argument to a full path.
  # Note that if you pass just a script filename (<script>), it'll be interpreted relative 
  # to the current directory rather than based on an $env:PATH search; to do the latter, 
  # pass (Get-Command <script>).Source
  if ($LiteralPath -notmatch '^(?:[a-z]:)?[\\/]') { $LiteralPath = Convert-Path -LiteralPath $LiteralPath }

  # Check the script's first line for a shebang.
  $shebangLine = ''
  switch -Regex -File $LiteralPath {
    '^#!\s*(.*)\s*$' { # Matches a shebang line.

      # Save the shebang line and its embedded command.
      $shebangLine = $_
      $cmdLine = $Matches[1]

      Write-Verbose "Shebang line found in '$LiteralPath': $shebangLine"

      break # We're done now that we have the shebang line.

    }

    default { # no shebang line found -> open with default text editor

      # Note: We cannot use Invoke-Item or Start-Process, as that would
      #       reinvoke this handler, resulting in an infinite loop.
      #       The best we can do is to open the file in the default text editor.

      Write-Verbose "No shebang line, opening with default text editor: $LiteralPath"

      # Obtain the command line for the default text editor directly from the registry
      # at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\Open\command rather than via `cmd /c ftype`,
      # because assoc and ftype only ever report on and update the *machine-level* definitions at 
      # HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes
      $cmdLine = [environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables((((Get-ItemProperty -EA Ignore registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\Open\command).'(default)') -split '=')[-1])
      if (-not $cmdLine) { $cmdLine = 'NOTEPAD.EXE %1' } # Fall back to Notepad.

      break # We're done now that we know this file doesn't have a shebang line.

    }

  }

  # Parse the shebang line's embedded command line or the default-text-editor's command line into arguments.
  # Note: We use Invoke-Expression and Write-Output so as to support *quoted*
  #       arguments as well - though presumably rare in practice.
  #       If supporting quoted tokens isn't necessary, the next line can be replaced 
  #       with a strictly-by-whitespace splitting command:
  #         $cmdArgs = -split $cmdLine
  [array] $cmdArgs = (Invoke-Expression "Write-Output -- $($cmdLine -replace '\$', "`0")") -replace "`0", '$'

  if ($shebangLine) {

    # Extract the target executable name or path.
    # If the first argument is '/usr/bin/env', we skip it, as env (on Unix-like platforms) is merely used
    # to locate the true target executable in the Path.
    $exeTokenIndex = 0 + ($cmdArgs[0] -eq '/usr/bin/env')
    $exeNameOrPath = $cmdArgs[$exeTokenIndex]
    $exeFullPath = ''

    # Note: We do NOT pass any remaining arguments from the shebang line through.
    #       (Such arguments are rare anyway.)
    #       The rationale is that an interpreter that understands shebang lines will
    #       also respect such arguments when reading the file - this is true of at
    #       least py.exe, the Python launcher, and ruby.exe

    # Python is a special case: the Python launcher, py.exe, is itself
    # capable of interpreting shebang lines, so we defer to it.
    if ($exeNameOrPath -match '\bpython\d?') {
      # Ensure that 'py.exe' is available; if not, we fall back to the same approach 
      # as for all other executables.
      $exeFullPath = (Get-Command -CommandType Application py.exe -ErrorAction Ignore).Source
    }

    if (-not $exeFullPath) {
      # Try the executable spec. as-is first, should it actually contain a *Windows* path name.
      $exeFullPath = (Get-Command -CommandType Application $exeNameOrPath -ErrorAction Ignore).Source
      if (-not $exeFullPath) {
        # If not found, assume it is a Unix path that doesn't apply, and try to locate the hopefully
        # appropriate executable by its filename only, in the Path.
        $exeFullPath = (Get-Command -CommandType Application (Split-Path -Leaf -LiteralPath $exeNameOrPath) -ErrorAction Ignore).Source
      }
    }

    # Abort, if we can't find a suitable executable.
    if (-not $exeFullPath) { Throw "Could not find a suitable executable to run '$LiteralPath' based on its shebang line: $shebangLine" }

    # Synthesize the complete list of arguments to pass to the target exectuable.
    $passThruArgs = , $LiteralPath + $passThruArgs

  } else {  # NON-shebang-line files: invocation of default text editor

    $exeFullPath, [array] $editorArgs = $cmdArgs -replace '%1', ($LiteralPath -replace '\$', '$$')

    # Synthesize the complete list of arguments to pass to the target exectuable.
    # Replace the '%1' placeholder with the script's path.
    # Note that we don't really expect additional arguments to have been passed in this scenario,
    # and such arguments may be interpreted as additional file arguments by the editor.
    $passThruArgs = ($editorArgs -replace '"?%1"?', ($LiteralPath -replace '\$', '$$$$')) + $passThruArgs

    # If the editor is a GUI application, $LASTEXITCODE won't be set by PowerShell.
    # We set it to 0 here, as it has no value by default, and referencing it below with exit
    # would cause an error due to Set-StrictMode -Version 1.
    $LASTEXITCODE = 0
  }

  Write-Verbose "Executing: $exeFullPath $passThruArgs"

  # Invoke the target executable with all arguments.
  # Important:
  #  * We need to manually \-escape embeded " chars. in arguments
  #    because PowerShell, regrettably, doesn't do that automatically.
  #    However, even that may fail in edge cases in Windows PowerShell (fixed in PS Core), 
  #    namely when an unbalanced " char. is part of the first word - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604316/45375
  & $exeFullPath ($passThruArgs  -replace '"', '\"')

  # Pass the target executable's exit code through.
  # (In the case of invoking the default editor for non-shebang-line files, it 
  # won't have been set, if the editor is a GUI application.)
  exit $LASTEXITCODE
'@ |
    Set-Content -Encoding Utf8 -LiteralPath $helperScriptFullName

}

# === UNINSTALL
function uninstall {

  Write-Verbose ('Uninstalling shebang-script support for {0}:' -f ('the current user', 'ALL users')[$forAllUsers])

  Write-Verbose 'Removing file type information from the registry...'

  foreach ($regKey in $regkeyExtensionToFileType, $regkeyFileType) {
    if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $regKey) {
      Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -LiteralPath $regkey
    }
  }

  # Get the current $env:PATHEXT definition from the registry.
  $currPathExt = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATHEXT', ('User', 'Machine')[$forAllUsers])

  # Remove the "." entry from $env:PATHEXT
  $newPathExt = ($currPathExt -split ';' -ne '.') -join ';'
  if ($newPathExt -eq $currPathExt) {
    Write-Verbose "'.' is not contained in PATHEXT; nothing to do."
  } else {
    # For user-level uninstallations: as a courtesy, we compare the new PATHEXT value
    # to the machine-level one, and, if they're now the same, simply REMOVE the user-level definition.
    Write-Verbose "Removing '.' from PATHEXT..."
    if (-not $forAllUsers) {
      $machineLevelPathExt = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATHEXT', 'Machine')
      if ($newPathExt -eq $machineLevelPathExt) { $newPathExt = $null }
      Write-Verbose "User-level PATHEXT no longer needed, removing..."
    }
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATHEXT', $newPathExt, ('User', 'Machine')[$forAllUsers])
    # Also update for the running session
    $env:PATHEXT = if ($newPathExt) { $newPathExt } else { $machineLevelPathExt }
  }

  Write-Verbose "Removing helper PowerShell script..."
  if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $helperScriptFullName) {
    Remove-Item -Force -LiteralPath $helperScriptFullName
  }

}

# ---------------------- END: Internal helper functions

$forAllUsers = $Scope -eq 'AllUsers'
$verb = ('install', 'uninstall')[$Uninstall.IsPresent]
$operation = $verb + 'ation'

# If -Scope AllUsers was passed, ensure that the session is elevated.
$mustElevate = $forAllUsers -and -not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole('BUILTIN\Administrators')
if ($mustElevate) {
  Throw "In order to $verb for ALL users, you must run this script WITH ELEVATED PRIVILEGES (Run As Administrator)."
}

# --- Define names, registry and file locations.
# The path of the generic shebang runner script that we'll create below.
$helperScriptFullName = Join-Path ($HOME, $env:ALLUSERSPROFILE)[$forAllUsers] 'Invoke-ShebangScript.ps1'

# The name of the file type to create for extension-less files.
$fileTypeName = 'ShebangScript'

# Registry keys that need to be modified.
# "." represents extension-less files
$regkeyExtensionToFileType = 'registry::{0}\SOFTWARE\Classes\.' -f ('HKEY_CURRENT_USER', 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE')[$forAllUsers]
$regkeyFileType = 'registry::{0}\SOFTWARE\Classes\{1}' -f ('HKEY_CURRENT_USER', 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE')[$forAllUsers], $fileTypeName
# --- 

# Prompt for confirmation, unless -Force was passsed.
if ($Uninstall) { # UNINSTALL

  if (-not $Force -and -not $PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue(@"

You are about to UNINSTALL support for direct execution of extension-less
script files that have shebang lines.

Uninstallation will be performed for $(("the CURRENT USER only`n(invoke as admin with -Scope AllUsers to change that)", 'ALL USERS')[$forAllUsers]).

IMPORTANT: Uninstallation will only be effective if it is performed in the same
           (implied) -Scope as the original installation.

The following modifications to your system will be performed:

  * "." will be persistently REMOVED from your `$env:PATHEXT variable.

  * The following registry keys will be REMOVED:

      $($regkeyExtensionToFileType -replace '^registry::')
      $($regkeyFileType -replace '^registry::')

  * The following helper PowerShell script will be REMOVED:

    $helperScriptFullName 

Press ENTER to proceed, or Ctrl-C to abort.
"@, "Shebang-Script Direct-Execution Support - Uninstallation")) { # , $true, [ref] $null, [ref] $null)) {
    exit 1
  }

  # Call the uninstallation helper function
  uninstall

} else {  # INSTALL

  if (-not $Force -and -not $PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue(@"

You are about to install support for direct execution of Unix-style scripts 
that do not have a filename extension and instead define the interpreter to run
them with via shebangline ("#!/path/to/interpreter").

Support will be installed for $(("the CURRENT USER only`n(invoke as admin with -Scope AllUsers to change that)", 'ALL USERS')[$forAllUsers]).

Once installed, you will be able to run such scripts by direct invocation,
via a helper PowerShell script that analyzes the shebang line and calls the
appropriate interpreter.

CAVEATS:

  * ENABLING THIS INVOCATION MECHANISM IS A SECURITY RISK, because any
    plain-text file without an extension that has a shebang line
    effectively becomes executable, potentially bypassing security features
    that focus on files that have extensions known to be executable.

  * AS OF POWERSHELL CORE 6.2.0, direct execution of such extension-less files
    from PowerShell INVARIABLY RUNS IN A NEW CONSOLE WINDOW, WHICH MAKES USE
    FROM POWERSHELL VIRTUALLY USELESS.
    However, this is a BUG that should be fixed; see:
      https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7769

The following modifications to your system will be performed:

  * "." will be added persistently to your `$env:PATHEXT variable, to enable
    direct execution of filenames without extension.

    NOTE: If you install with -Scope CurrentUser (the default), a static 
    user-level copy of the machine-level PATHEXT environment variable is 
    created, unless already present.

  * The following registry locations will be created or replaced to define a
    new file type for extension-less filenames:

      $($regkeyExtensionToFileType -replace '^registry::')
      $($regkeyFileType -replace '^registry::')

  * The helper PowerShell script will be created in:

    $helperScriptFullName 

NOTE: Any existing registry definitions or helper script will be REPLACED.

Press ENTER to proceed, or CTRL-C to abort.
"@, "Shebang-Script Direct-Execution Support - Installation")) {
    # !! The prompt defaults to *Yes* (!)
    # !! Sadly, if we wanted the prompt to be default to *No*, we'de be forced 
    # !! to also present pointless 'Yes/No to *All*' prompts, which would be confusing.
    # !! See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9428
    exit 1
  }

  # Call the installation helper function
  install
}

Write-Verbose "Shebang-support ${operation} completed."

if (-not $Force) {
  Write-Host "Shebang-support ${operation} completed."
}

exit 0
```

---

<sup>[1] In *Windows PowerShell*, you can use `Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.` to find extension-less files more conveniently and efficiently, but this feature is broken in PowerShell *Core* as of v6.2.0 - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9430).</sup>

Comment: Although your method seem very nice as it is pure PS native, I think my method of using the results from *assoc* and *ftype* is easier to parse. At least for already installed interpreters when using a switch statement. That said, I was hoping to find a native PS or **exe** version of those, and not having to go via *cmd* to get that info. This should be fairly straight forward as the number of popular interpreters are humanly finite. Either way, what really surprised me was how (python?) installer chose to butcher the shebang line upon installation, which seem insane & unportable behavior.

Comment: @not2qubit: Agreed, quiet modification of the shebang lines sounds very problematic. You don't need to call `cmd.exe` you can access the registry directly. Either way, you won't get the desired behavior, because PowerShell will launch a new console window whenever you invoke an extension-less Python file, at least with the current versions, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @not2qubit: Also, you only need `assoc` and `ftype` _once_, to install the extension-less handler; they won't help you in finding the appropriate interpreter when later analyzing shebang lines in the generic handler. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to use them for 2 different purposes in the same script. (1) To install the *testing* script (itself) for the `.` association, as in OP. (2) To parse the shebang and compare it to what's already in *ftype*. If it is present,use *that*, or if not, use our own exe/path. This would essentially replace native behavior. I haven't used the new 6.2 console yet, so that sound a bit concerning. What is the point of starting a new console for these scripts? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @not2qubit: You cannot use `assoc` and `ftype` for (2), at least not directly. Instead, use PowerShell's `Get-Command` to find the interpreter on a best-effort basis. The problem with execution in a _new_ console window affects Windows PowerShell and PowerShell Core equally. Please see my substantial update, which clarifies the risks and limitations of a generic solution and provides a fully functional - but nontrivial - solution in the bottom section.

Comment: This look very promising. The only thing I don't like is that the script is having to create *wrapper* scripts in order to function. This just seem like a poor hack. Can't it be replaced with one script that instead load or updates a CSV file containing the location of the original scripts?

Comment: @not2qubit: There is just _one_ script, and it's a _generic launcher_ script - it's embedded  in the installer script and saved to a file during installation. It _dynamically_ locates the appropriate interpreter when it is passed a script file path by the Windows shell. The only reason I embedded the launcher script in the installer was to provide a self-contained script for this answer; if I were to publish this, I'd create a module, inside of which the launcher script would live.

Comment: Ok, then I don't understand what you mean when you say: `"For every extension-less Python script somescript, a companion somescript.ps1 file is created"`. That sound to me that for every `my1` and `my2`, there will be a corresponding `my1.ps1` and `my2.ps1`?

Comment: @not2qubit, yes, sorry - I thought you were talking about the generic `Install-ShebangSupport.ps1` solution at the bottom (which, due to the linked bug, won't work in PowerShell at the moment, only in `cmd.exe`). Therefore, you must either use individual wrapper scripts, as in the solution at the top or create analogous _functions_ (both solutions have the advantage of being faster, because no PowerShell child process is involved). In either case, the code to create them must be run every time new scripts are added, whereas the bottom solution is a one-time installation with a single script.