# powershell: run executable without extension

Tags: windows, powershell, executable

I have a powershell script which needs to run a number of executables.

The executables have no extension, and cannot be renamed.

They all have the format `<something>_test`.

When I try to run them using powershell:

```
& $test_bin | Tee-Object -FilePath $log_output_file
```

It fails with the error

```
Cannot run a document in the middle of a pipeline
```

I tried setting PATHEXT (`$env:PATHEXT="$env:PATHEXT;_test"`) but that didn't help. I'm guessing it only supports actual extensions.

Is there anyway to tell windows that a specific file is an executable, or to tell powershell to execute a file even though it thinks it's a document?

Comment: What happens when you run only `& $test_bin`? ... I mean without the `| Tee-Object -FilePath $log_output_file` ...

Comment: Then it opens a dialog to select how I want to open the file.

Comment: Have you tried using `Start-Process`? Why is renaming not an option?` On Windows systems executables usually have an extension. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Yeah I think I'll have to rename in the end because for example the golang exec library requires an extension too, so there's no general solution here.

Comment: Hmmm ... the solution would be to follow well known system standards. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried setting PATHEXT (`$env:PATHEXT="$env:PATHEXT;_test"`) but that didn't help

- You'd have to use `.` to represent files *without* an extension
  (`$env:PATHEXT="$env:PATHEXT;."`)
- Additionally, you'd have to define a *file type* (e.g. via `cmd.exe`'s internal `assoc` and `ftype` commands) that invokes a helper application to facilitate the execution.

  - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55619189/45375) shows such a definition in the context of emulating shebang-line support on Windows, but it ultimately won't help you - see next point.
- However, as of PowerShell (Core) 7.3.x, even if that wouldn't enough, because PowerShell - unlike `cmd.exe` - then invokes the helper application *in a new window*; this problematic behavior is the subject of [GitHub issue #9430](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9430).

---

**Workarounds**:

- If it is sufficient to support only redirecting the executable's output to *files* (and capturing  stdout and stderr in *separate* files) - you can use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) with the `-NoNewWindow` switch and the `-RedirectStandardOutput` and `-RedirectStandardError` parameters; e.g.:

  ```
  Start-Process -Wait -NoNewWindow $test_bin -RedirectStandardOutput $log_output_file
  ```

  - *Character-encoding caveat:* It is the encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding` that is used for the files created by `-RedirectStandardOutput` and `-RedirectStandardError`, which defaults the legacy system locale's OEM code page; (temporarily) set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to the desired encoding as needed. The same applies analogously to stdout output that PowerShell directly receives from external programs (see next point).
- If you want the usual PowerShell experience - synchronous execution in the same window, with the executable process' standard streams (stdin, stdout, stderr) connected to PowerShell's streams - more work is needed:

  - Helper function `Invoke-ExtensionLess` (source code) below is a *simple* proof-of-concept that uses .NET APIs ([`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process), [`System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo)) to support directly streaming the executable's *stdout* output to the PowerShell pipeline, but it lacks support for streaming pipeline (stdin) *input* (adding such support would require quite a bit more effort).
  - A sample invocation would look like this:

    ```
    Invoke-ExtensionLess $test_bin arg1 arg2 | 
      ForEach-Object { "[$_]" } # sample pipeline processing.
    ```

---

**`Invoke-ExtensionLess` source code**:

```
# Note: No support for stdin input.
function Invoke-ExtensionLess {
  param($exe)
  # Find the executable's full path
  $exePath = if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $exe) { Convert-Path -LiteralPath $exe } else { (Get-Command -ErrorAction Stop -Type Application $exe).Path }
  $process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start(
    [System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo] @{
      FileName = $exePath
      Arguments = $args.ForEach({ $a = $_ -replace '(?<!\\)(\\*)"', '$1$1\"'; ($a, "`"$a`"")[$_ -match ' '] }) -join ' '
      UseShellExecute = $false
      RedirectStandardOutput = $true
      RedirectStandardError = $false
    }
  )
  # Relay stdout output to the pipeline line by line (while not redirecting stderr output).
  while (-not $process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    $process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()
  }
  # Wait for the process to exit...
  $process.WaitForExit()
  # ... and report its exit code.
  $global:LASTEXITCODE = $process.ExitCode
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
# Define a function which executes any file
function Start-ProcessEx ($filePath)
{
    $psi = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo]::new()
    $psi.FileName = $filePath
    $psi.UseShellExecute = $false # This is the key to run file as executable when it has non-executable extension
    return [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)
}

Start-ProcessEx -filePath 'C:\Program Files\Speedtest\Speedtest.randomextension'
```

There should be more ways to execute file with non-executable extension, this is one of variants.